# Is Django (especially Django Rest Framework) really synchronous?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know some concepts that Django (DRF) is synchronous and it has some workers, but I know little about this.

I tried to verify this and created this view at the address **http://localhost:8000/my-view/**:

```
def my_view(request):
    # Simulate some time-consuming task
    time.sleep(10)
    return HttpResponse("Response after 10 seconds")
```

I proceeded to open 7 terminals and execute the same command on each of them within a range of 1-2 seconds (almost simultaneously):

```
curl http://localhost:8000/my-view/ -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

--> and the result was that in each terminal I received response in 10-12 seconds.

Here is the question, if Django is synchronous so why it did not take 70 seconds to execute these requests one by one?

The only explanation I can think of is that it uses multithreading.

Comment: It is synchronous AND multi-threaded.  The two concepts are orthogonal.   In this context, synchronous means that one request uses one thread and the thread is not relinquished during processing of that request.  But "synchronous" doesn't imply that >all< requests use the same thread and are processed one at a time.  In your use-case, Django is using multiple request threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is synchronous (except [when it's not](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/async/)), but it doesn't have a concept of "some workers". The application server running the Django application might have a concept of workers of some sort.

The default `runserver` development server is indeed multi-threading.

Run with `python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload` for a single-process, single-thread development server.